# Opening a dialog box from a table cell button

Tags: java, dialog, swt, tableviewer

I need to allow my users to edit a filename value in the my table.  So in my tableviewer I added the code to create and display the edit button(s) in my last column.  I have this working.

When they click on the edit button, I want a dialog box to open with the filename in a textbox with a save and cancel button.

So I created FileNameDialog class.

My question is: Where do I create the dialog?

- Do I create a method in the base dialog and call the method from the tableviewer

```
class SelectionListener implements Listener {
    TableItem item;
    Button editButton;
    Object element;

    public SelectionListener(TableItem item, Button deleteButton, Object element) {
        this.item = item;
        this.editButton = deleteButton;
        this.element = element;
    }

    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        AplotPDFDataModel.FileNameData selected = (( AplotPDFDataModel.FileNameData)element);
        int index = AplotPDFDataModel.getInstance().getIndexOf(selected);
        pdfDialog.showEditFileNameDialog();  <<++++++++HERE

        Table table = getTable();
        table.getColumn(5).pack();
        table.getColumn(5).setWidth(100);
    }
} // End SelectionListener Class
```

- Do I just create a method in the tableviewer and create the dialog there?

```
public void showEditFileNameDialog() {
    editFileNameDialog = new EditFileNameDialog(getShell());
    editFileNameDialog.create();
    editFileNameDialog.getShell().setSize(300, 200);
    editFileNameDialog.open();  
}
```

What is the best procedure for opening a dialog from a button click in a tableviewer?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What are the two options? Normally you would just create and show the dialog in the `handleEvent` method of the `Listener`.

Comment: I did not know if that was good practice mixing dialog code with tableviewer code, but it does make sense to put it there.  I was looking for assurance that was the right place.  Thanks

Comment: yes it was, you answered the question.  Being I am creating this dialog in the tableviewer, what do I need to pass in to the dialog from the tableviewer?  Do i need to pass in the parent composite, get a shell?  Do I have to pass anything in?  I am refereeing to the constructor of my dialog class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would just create and show the `Dialog` in the `handleEvent` method of the `Listener`.

To get a `Shell` that you can hand to the `Dialog` either of the following will do:

```
new EditFileNameDialog(getTable().getShell());
```

or

```
new EditFileNameDialog(new Shell());
```